# A 95% minimal rectangle problem

Tags: discrete-optimization

In May, there was a question on Stackoverflow, [3 dimension prediction limit in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44069854/3-dimension-prediction-limit-in-r), a special form of the "smallest enclosing rectangle" problem. Because the problem has not been solved there, I would like to formulate it here as a problem in discrete optimization and hoping for an efficient algorithm to solve it exactly.

> Given N points in, say, two dimensions, find an axes-parallel rectangle
>   of minimal area that encloses at least 95% of the points.

I understand there's not always a solution, for example when all the points lie on the boundary of a rectangle. So let us assume the points are somehow in *general position*, even such that no two points have exactly the same x- or y-coordinates.

I know that a/the solution can be found by looping through all x- and y-coordinates, resp. those below the 0.05 or above the 0.95 quantiles. Of course, I hope for a smarter and more efficient algorithmic approach.

Comment: I don't see how your solution sketch is going to work. The problem is to find the best balance between reducing the x and y extents (from the rectangle containing all points). And this involves considering both coordinates simultaneously.

Comment: @Walter Looping through the x- and y-coordinates means to enumerate and test *all* possible solutions. It will find the minimum with certainty. The problem is that it is not efficient, O(N^4) steps, and will not really work for more points or higher dimensions.

Comment: @HansWerner Suppose you are given $N$ points in the plane. There are [deterministic algorithms](http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:1834660:2/component/escidoc:1857755/MPI-I-93-116.pdf) that compute a set of $k$ points (for any $2 \le k \le N$) with a smallest enclosing parallel axes-parallel square. This should be what you want, right?

Comment: @GoHokies  Thanks for pointing this out. Such a report and the literature it is referring to are quite helpful. Still, it ends up finding a square and not a rectangle, so the problem is not really solved. Seeing the effort finding a square, I am wondering whether finding a rectangle will be easier or more difficult.

Comment: @HansWerner  These algorithms can find rectangle-shaped enclosures as well, as demonstrated in [_Smallest $k$-point enclosing rectangle and square of arbitrary orientation_ by Das et al.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019005000621)

Comment: @HansWerner see also [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019097002123)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem reads

> Given $N$ points in, say, two dimensions, find an axes-parallel rectangle
>    of minimal area that encloses at least 95% of the points.

This is essentially equivalent to the following problem (the *smallest $k$-point enclosing rectangle*), for which efficient deterministic algorithms are known:

> Given $N$ points in two dimensions and an integer $k \le N$, find an axes-parallel square or rectangle of minimal area that encloses $k$ of the points.

Some references:

[*Enclosing $k$ points in the smallest axis parallel rectangle*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019097002123) - Segal and Kedem, *Information Processing Letters*, 1998

[*Finding $k$ points with a smallest enclosing square*](http://pubman.mpdl.mpg.de/pubman/item/escidoc:1834660:2/component/escidoc:1857755/MPI-I-93-116.pdf) - Smid, 1995.

[*Smallest $k$-point enclosing rectangle and square of arbitrary orientation*](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0020019005000621) - Das et al., *Information Processing Letters*, 2005

Answer (score 0):

You can try non-deterministic algorithms, such as simulated annealing. They are not sure to get the mathematically exact answer, but they can get a good approximation fairly fast.

If $d$ is the dimension, then there are 2$d$ values to be set (locations of two opposite corners). 
1. Start with corners at 2.5% and 97.5% (good approximations if the distribution is fairly well behaved). This is for 1D, otherwise $(1-0.95^{1/d})/2$ instead of 2.5%.
2. Pick two of these 2$d$ values, increase (resp. decrease) one of the two and decrease (resp. increase) the other to get back to 95%. If the area is smaller, keep it. Otherwise, apply your policy (e.g. simulated annealing: some probability to keep it that goes down with time).
3. Repeat.

Comment: No, simulated annealing and other evolutionary approaches are in general not appropriate for solving discrete optimization problems -- I do have some experience therewith.  
Plus, sorry if I did not make this clear enough, I am interested in solving this problem *exactly*, and thus preferably in a way that could classify as combinatorial optimization.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sketch of an algorithm, though I have no proof that it always produces the minimum.

```
goal = 0.95*points.size()
rect = smallest_rectangle_containing_all(points)
while(rect.number_of_points() > goal):
    old_rect = rect
    rect.maximally_shrink_by_omitting_at_least_one_point()
if(rect.number_of_points() < goal)
    rect = old_rect;
```

where `rectangle::maximally_shrink_by_omitting_at_least_one_point()` is a bit tricky to get right, but otherwise is straightforward (I leave its implementation to you).

Comment: No, this is *not* a valid solution. Such step-by-step procedures do not work for most discrete optimization problems. For the Stackoverflow example above your approach generates a rectangle of area 21.0846. The true minimum, by the way, is 19.16451. I cannot accept your proposal as it is incorrect and does not identify the minimum area rectangle.